# Get attribute from window opening

Tags: javascript, window.open, selectors-api, getattribute

To get the attribute from opening window JABRA website, i tried this JS-Code.

```
var popup = window.open("http://www.jabra.com.de/Support/warranty-checker");

popup.alert("Hello");

var yaya = popup.document.querySelectorAll(".serial-number")[0].getAttribute("type");

popup.alert("getting variable: "+yaya);

popup.alert("World!");
```

While opening the window JABRA, it alert "Hello", but won't get an attribute and the last alert "World" won't show up.

I tried difference JS-Code like:

```
var yaya = popup.querySelectorAll(".serial-number")[0].getAttribute("type");

var yaya = popup.querySelectorAll(".serial-number").getAttribute("type");
```

Please what is the solution!

Comment: As far as I know you cannot access the DOM of a window opened through `window.open`. You should fetch that page.

Comment: thx for reply, could you please show me the little example of this code, how to fetch that page?

Comment: I'm not really sure how to do it normally, because of cross-domain restrictions. Using a userscript manager like Greasemonkey you can fetch pages from different domains with GM.xmlHttpRequest. And using a WebExtension you can also accomplish that by fetching the page from the event page of the extension.

Answer (score 0):

Is the window being opened on the same domain/host, or on a different one?
 If they are different, then unfortunately this is a [security constraint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) by browsers to prohibit cross-site scripting.

The suggested approach is to use the [postMessage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) to safely communicate between two `Window` objects (frames etc).

Comment: thx for reply, i am using it on a different one, also normal with testing the datafile test.html, then  I put it in browser only to have acces to get an Attribute from this Jabra websites.